# Can I get Exception Error from the Method I am running?

Tags: c#, attributes, xunit

Is there a way I can get the exception to be fed in BeforeAfterTestAttribute? My goal is to log out the Method error if it is not executed correctly and perform other actions. This comes more or less from [This Post](https://hamidmosalla.com/2018/08/30/xunit-beforeaftertestattribute-how-to-run-code-before-and-after-test/)

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method)]
class ReportBeforeAtribute : BeforeAfterTestAttribute
{
    public override void Before(MethodInfo methodUnderTest)
    {
        Trace.Log("Starting Message");
    }

    public override  void After(MethodInfo methodUnderTest)
    {
        Trace.Log("Method Ended Fine ");
    }

    public void After(MethodInfo methodUnderTest, Exception ex)
    {
        Trace.Log("Exeption " + ex.Message);
    }
}
```

The attribute would be used here:

```
  [ReportBefore]
    public class TestClass
    {
        [Theory]
        public async Task CheckMethod()
        {
        //Here Is code which Either runs ok or not
        //If breaks I want to pass the Exception to The Attribute in the 
        // After Method
        }
    }
```

From the above code The first and second part works, though the third method is what I want to create, this is what is not working.

is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: How did you test the first two methods? And what did you try for the third? Can you show some test code?

Comment: As @khlr pointed out there is not enough information here to help you - the code in attribute's methods don't get executed unless something calls those methods. Clearly just adding a new method not going to do anything (for reference the attribute you are talking about does not have an extension point you are trying to use - https://github.com/xunit/xunit/blob/master/src/xunit.core/Sdk/BeforeAfterTestAttribute.cs). So voting to close to let you add some details how *your* code invokes this method on the attribute.

Comment: So If the code breaks somewher ein CheckMethod I want to get that exception to the attribute to use it in the After Method (or as well Before) method to be run. Added as well the Post from which I am trying to implement.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the exception not to break your test, you should probably expect it. The link describes a little how you can work with exceptions.

https://fluentassertions.com/exceptions/

Comment: No, not quite, because I don't expect any errors. I want to mimic the try-catch statement on the method, only controlling by attribute the catch result.